# Unethical behaviour in a work place, possible fraud

Tags: resignation, fraud

Recently, I started growing a suspicion that the management in my company can accept certain sources of profits from shady customers. Let's say that to me it seems to be a fraud, to management it is a "grey area".

I've read that 20% of all online advertising is fraud but I liked to believe there is less percentage in our company. Lately, I started suspecting otherwise. Few things made me aware that ethics is not one of the list of priorities of the top management.

Perhaps I am overreacting, but my personal values are not aligned with some ways of making a business. I am ready to hand in the notice letter and was hoping to leave without burning bridges.

I am personally not participating in any of the suspicious activities, up to my knowledge. Should I break the contract with the employer and leave immediately or should I rather stay till the end of my notice?

I would appreciate any advice on what should be my next steps.

Comment: Have you considered already other jobs to apply in case you decide to hand the notice and leave?

Comment: @GrayCygnus I am going to roll a dice on starting my own company.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, if you can prove that top executives are engaging in fraud, you could be protected in your contract breakage by whistleblower laws that would prevent retaliatory actions by the company, depending on your country of residence. Most employment contracts also have an escape clause for illegal activity. You would, of course, have to formally report such fraud to the police, which would be a legal matter outside of the scope of The Workplace.

Fraud or no fraud, though, it sounds like you're finding that you're less and less of a fit for the company that you would have hoped.

Breaking your contract would definitely constitute burning your bridge with the company, as you would be breaking your promise to the company, and the company would likely lose the (albeit short-term) investment they have placed in you. I would definitely consider the implications of this. As a result of your contract breakage, will you owe the company a lot of money as part of a buyout? Is there a non-compete agreement in that contract? Are you planning to work with them again in your own company, even as a vendor? Are you planning to work with anyone from the company again (remember, people move between companies too)?

Fulfilling your contract would allow you to leave the company on a much more amicable note, and it could also possibly net you a reference to use when looking for jobs with other companies. It can also allow you to partner with your old company or old colleagues if the circumstances arise.

Overall, I would only break the contract if you find that you cannot possibly find yourself ever returning to work with this company and/or that the company is asking you to do something illegal or unethical.

Answer (score -1):

Breach of contract can be serious, depending on the country. This could be trouble for you. Then consider that if they are involved in fraud, they won't be afraid to lie about you to make you pay.

Use the usual, recommended steps: Find a new job. Sign a contract with the new company. Give notice. Work your notice. Start new job. Be happy.

(Some people worry a lot about "burning bridges". I assume this is a bridge that you want burnt to the ground and never re-built).